# I want to display the top 10 upregulated and downregulated genes in a volcano plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My dataframe New.df.7vsNO has a column named Genes in which I want to be able to display the top 10 upregulated and downregulated genes in my data. I am not sure on how to write that so that it can filter out that on the graph. Additionally, I want to actually label the data points on the graph, I thought doing label = Genes would display at least some of the names of the Genes.

```
ggplot(New.df.7vsNO, aes(x = log2FC, y = logpv, col = diffexpressed, label = Genes)) + geom_point() + theme_minimal() + scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "black")) + geom_vline(xintercept=c(-1.6, 1.6), col="red") +
        geom_hline(yintercept=-log10(0.05), col="red")
```

```
structure(list(log2FC = c(2.5576, -1.7629, 4.5593, -1.6414, 4.7747, 
1.9217, 2.5951, -2.4236, 4.2056, -2.8089, -2.1215, -1.7551, 7.6618, 
1.9732, 1.768, -1.7532, 2.1137, -7.4119, -5.0595, -1.6435), logpv = c(6.23062267392386, 
2.4454139371159, 6.87289520163519, 2.41294040382783, 9.84466396253494, 
3.31880400398931, 5.49214412830417, 5.38090666937326, 10.3914739664228, 
7.39254497678533, 4.19928292171762, 2.43023996241365, 3.67370511218151, 
3.17656489822122, 2.45950785169463, 2.70542356079838, 3.13990167030148, 
3.04151256697968, 14.8041003475908, 2.43438827509794), diffexpressed = c("UP", 
"DOWN", "UP", "DOWN", "UP", "UP", "UP", "DOWN", "UP", "DOWN", 
"DOWN", "DOWN", "UP", "UP", "UP", "DOWN", "UP", "DOWN", "DOWN", 
"DOWN"), Genes = c("Ngfr", "Axin2", "Igsf5", "Dlat", "Scnn1g", 
"Ckmt1", "Tmprss2", "Pparg", "Sema4f", "Hk2", "Pxmp4", "Scn4a", 
"Slc13a2", "Timp1", "Uhrf1", "Cnn1", "Ube2c", "Rhbg", "Tmem79", 
"Cyp51")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

Comment: To help us to help you could you please make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data ? Simply type e.g. `dput(head(NAME_OF_DATASET, 20))` into the console, which gives the first 20 rows of your df, and copy & paste the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.

Comment: BTW: ... you have to add a `geom_text` to plot the labels.

Comment: Hi Stefan, let me know if that worked. Thank you.

Comment: Yep. Worked. (;

Answer (score 1):

You can get a dataframe with the top genes by making e.g. use of `dplyr::top_n`. Instead of the top 10 I used the top 3 for exmaple purposes. Also, don't know that much about genes so I have chosen `logpv` as weighting variable.

This dataframe can then be used inside a second `geom_point` where I have chosen a larger size.

To get the labels I went for `ggrepel::geom_text_repel` which does its best to avoid overlapping labels:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

topdown <- New.df.7vsNO %>% 
  group_by(diffexpressed) %>% 
  dplyr::top_n(3, wt = logpv)

ggplot(New.df.7vsNO, aes(x = log2FC, y = logpv, col = diffexpressed, label = Genes)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(show.legend = FALSE) + 
  #geom_text(vjust = -.1, show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_point(data = topdown, size = 3, show.legend = FALSE) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "black")) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=c(-1.6, 1.6), col="red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=-log10(0.05), col="red")
```

[image]